How to get someone's all joined groups/channels by user id by telethon?
I'm wrting a python use telethon. How to get someone's all joined groups/channels by user id?
I haven't found any effective methods to implement this functionality, and it seems that there is no relevant content available on search engines. My ideal implementation is to specify a user ID and be able to retrieve all the groups or channels that this user has joined. This functionality is also available in the app. I would be grateful for any answers or help. Thank you all!

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

This feature has been removed from the Telethon module for some time.
I use another method, I get the last 10,000 messages and extract their user idfrom
# Iterate over all messages in a chat, starting from the oldest message (by using reversed).
async for message in reversed(client.get_messages(chat)):
    print(message.sender.name, message.text_html)

More examples are available in the client.get_messages documentation.
